# EDMX in gridview dynamically creating columns according to data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, entity-framework-4

I have been struggling with this for a while now. 
I want to dynamically create data columns using the entity framework.

```
var query2 = (from c in dbc.FridayTimeSlots
              where c.RoundType == "Back 9"
              select c);
grvF2.Columns.Clear();
grvF2.DataSource = query2.ToList();
grvF2.Columns.Add(new BoundField { DataField = "TeeTime", HeaderText = "Tee-Off Time" });
grvF2.Columns.Add(new CommandField { HeaderText = "Select", SelectText = "Select Time", ButtonType = ButtonType.Link, ShowSelectButton = true });
grvF2.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "TimeID" };
grvF2.DataBind();
```

My problem, I want to only display the command field when the data field TeeTime = "something" and when TeeTime = "somethinig else" I don't want the commandfield there.

If tried just about everything but I can't get the solution. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridView's `RowDataBound` you can find the `LinkButton` and  make `Visible=false`:

```
protected void grvF2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = e.Row as GridViewRow;
    if (gvr != null && gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        LinkButton lb = gvr.Cells[1].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
        if (lb != null && gvr.Cells[0].Text.ToLower() != "something")
        {
            lb.Visible = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Assuming that you have this markup for the `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvF2" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="grvF2_DataBound"     
    OnRowDataBound="grvF2_RowDataBound" >
</asp:GridView>
```

And the output may look like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried something similar based on what you showed me. It works like a charm.